# Insert many rows in Gnumeric

Tags: gnumeric

Gnumeric is a spreadsheet program.

There is `Insert 1 row` in the row context menu.

But how to insert many row?
Anything better than selecting `Insert 1 row` many times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Highlight the number of rows you want to insert, then right-click and from the context menu select "Insert *N* Rows". That many empty rows will be inserted immediately above the first highlighted row.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Insert row from row context menu or from insert menu on top.
Repeat
Repeat

Now, select all 3 rows (3 is just an example, you can do 4, or however many is a convenient block for you)

Press F4, it will insert 3 rows and will do that each time that you press f4.  F4 is the repeat last action key normally...